# Redirect traffic from a specific subfolder to a different domain with preserved path in .htaccess

Tags: seo, htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

How can I write a .htaccess mod_rewrite rule to redirect all traffic to a specific subfolder to a different subdomain, but include all the trailing URI and url structure and in a SEO friendly way.

ie.

```
www.example.com/photogallery/2010/January-Spring-Photos/
```

to

```
example.site/2010/January-Spring-Photos/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this into the root's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^photogallery/(.*)$ http://photos.site.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: I just killed a phpbb site and used this to redirect to a static html page. `RewriteRule ^view* http://www.wsmcbbs.info/index.html [L,R=301,QSA]`